# Block string with iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall

I want to block custom string request on my server..

I am doing all but after some time my Apache is going down or work too slow. Server is Xeon E3-1230 with 32GB of RAM running Ubuntu

Here is my `iptables` command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 88 -m --string "Blabla" -j DROP
```

Maybe do i need some extra config? Or some config in apache?

Thanks

Comment: What is the _real_ string?

Comment: Dropping packets by matching random strings creates really hard to diagnose problems like you are having. There should be a better approach to solve the actual problem you are having.

Comment: Example keyword STU